# pip install_requires clones from git repository, but repository content is missing

Tags: git, pip, dependencies

I need to install dependency from private git repository. It looks like pip install -e . worked OK, but the content of the repository is missing.

My setup.py contains:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="",
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        "db@git+ssh://private_repo_git_path@master#egg=1.0.0"
    ]
)
```

I am running the installation with
`venv\Scripts\pip install -e .` (windows)

```
Installation logs says:
Collecting db@ git+ssh://private_repo_git_path@master#egg=1.0.0
  Cloning ssh://****@private_repo_git_path (to revision master) to c:\users\...\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-lobhunuh\db
  Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@private_repo_git_path' 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lobhunuh\db'
```

...

```
Installing collected packages: ..., db, ...
    Running setup.py install for db ... done
    ...
```

Please, any ideas, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any error. "*Running setup.py install for db ... done*" Where do you think `pip` got that `setup.py` if not from the repository? If you think there is a problem we need more information: code, error messages, [mcve].

Comment: That's exactly the point. There's no problem displayed in console, everything looks fine. I thought the setup.py is from the temporary location. I'll try to reproduce it with public repo on github.

Comment: If there're no errors displayed in console what's the problem? `setup.py` is definitely from a temporary location because `pip` cloned the repository into a temporary location.

Comment: Stuff from pypi gets into ven\Lib\site-packages, but I can't find the content of the repository anywhere in my project, nor elsewhere.

Comment: I think `pip` clones the repository into a temporary location, installs it and removes after.

Comment: But that doesn't make much sense. How am I supposed to use the code from the repository then?

Comment: Install and import in your libraries/programs. Upgrade using `pip install --upgrade db@ git+ssh://…` If you want something more clone the repository manually and install from it using `pip install .`

Comment: OK, I made 2 public repositories: [dependency test](https://github.com/pmitko/pip_git_dependency_test) and [dependency](https://github.com/pmitko/pip_git_dependency). When I run setup.bat (which creates venv and then runs pip install ., I get the following error: pip-git-dependency-test 0.0.0 requires db@ git+ssh://git@github.com/pmitko/pip_git_dependency.git@master#egg=db, which is not installed.

Comment: According [pip ref](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#git), non-editable install is cloned into temporary place and then installed normally. I would expect under "installed normally" that pip places the content of the dependency repo into standard venv lib dir.

Comment: However running venv\Scripts\pip install -e git+ssh://git@github.com/pmitko/pip_git_source.git@master#egg=db explicitly gives no error (with clean start of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though newer versions of Python 3 are able to import directories without a `__init__.py` file as packages, these directories still need to be added to the distributions of Python projects.

In this case *setuptools* is in charge of the packaging and its [`find_packages` function](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) is in charge of finding the packages automatically. But as far as I know this function only detects packages based on the presence of a `__init__.py` file in the directories. Directories without such a file are then either not added to the distributions of the project or not installed (not entirely sure, which it is).

Maybe try [*setuptools* `find_namespace_packages`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#find-namespace-packages) instead. This function seems to be designed to consider any directory containing at least one Python file as a package even without the usual `__init__.py` file. Which obviously can have side-effects, for example a `test` directory should not be a package installed with the project, even though it does contain Python code.

From my point of view, there is not much drawback to adding the `__init__.py` files anyway, so that would be my recommendation.

Comment: About the installation process. But you already answered it in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860692/pip-install-requires-clones-from-git-repository-but-repository-content-is-missi/60394204?noredirect=1#comment106837232_60393830). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found out what the problem was.
The dependency package didn't have the `__init__.py` file.
By adding the file in the root package folder, pip correctly installed the package as a dependency in `venv\Lib\site-packages` folder.

Python >= 3 doesn't require `__init__.py` to treat a folder as a package. I didn't think pip would handle this differently.

Comment: I believe it's not a _pip_ vs. _Python 3_ issue as mentioned, but a _packaging_ issue. In this case _setuptools_ is used to do the packaging and its [`find_packages` function](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) to find the packages automatically. But as far as I know this function only detects packages based on the presence of a `__init__.py` file in the directories. Directories without such a file are not added to the distributions of the project. Maybe try `find_namespace_packages` instead, but adding the `__init__.py` files is the better way.

Comment: That would make sense, thanks for the info. But when I use ```venv\Scripts\pip install git+https://github.com/pmitko/pip_git_dependency.git@ebf610f1deb02e04d3fa71e4cb92eda36d049978#egg=pip_git_dependency``` will it use also the find_packages function? Because this way pip won't create package neither.

Comment: Not sure on the details but I do not believe the `find_packages` or `find_namespace_packages` are executed at _install-time_ (when doing `pip install MyProject` for example) but only at _build-time_ / _packaging-time_ (when doing `python3 setup.py sdist` or `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel`). In this case (`pip install git+https://something.git`) _build_ happens immediately before _install_ so it may look like one single operation, but I am pretty sure it's still two different operations. So if the _packaging_ has an issue like this one then the _installed_ project will lack some packages.